# Logging out of Wordpress password protected pages with cookie timout?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, passwords

I'm using wordpress for a specific client because of their need to edit content themselves. With this, I'm using their page password protection, per client's request. The problem is, it seems that the cookie being set never times out. So, once the client enters the password, nobody ever has to enter the password again through the same browser on the same machine. This leaves it wide open for anybody to walk up to and enter. So, I assume the best way to address this is to set a timeout on the cookie. However, I'm not sure how to do that with the php function. Here's the whole function:

```
function post_password_required( $post = null ) {
    $post = get_post($post);

    if ( empty( $post->post_password ) )
        return false;

    if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] ) )
        return true;

    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
    $hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );

    $hash = wp_unslash( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] );
    if ( 0 !== strpos( $hash, '$P$B' ) )
        return true;

    return ! $hasher->CheckPassword( $post->post_password, $hash );
}
```

Really, I'd like to have the cookie expire when the browser closes, and otherwise every few hours. Any advice on what to add to make the cookie expire after it's set?

I believe it would probably have to be added to this line:

```
$hash = wp_unslash( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] );
```

Thanks ahead of time for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a much, much easier way to do this, using the [`post_password_expires`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_password_expires/) filter. By default, the cookie expires 10 days from creation. **To turn this into a session cookie, return 0.** The following should be added to your theme's *functions.php*:

```
function custom_password_cookie_expiry( $expires ) {
    return 0;  // Make it a session cookie
}
add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'custom_password_cookie_expiry' );
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I found one other thing in wp-login.php:

    $expire = apply_filters( 'post_password_expires', time() + 10 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );

However, this doesn't seem to change anything when I change the time() setting, with or without your custom function present. Any idea why?

Comment: You should never edit core WordPress files (i.e. anything outside of `/wp-content/` and `wp-config.php`). There will almost always be unintended results. Why do you feel you need to edit that function?

Comment: "Why do you feel you need to edit that function?"
- Because it sets a password cookie expiration.

Comment: You should be doing that using a filter, as described in my answer above. Again, **never edit core WordPress files**. You can make this cookie either time or session based...but not both (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: I'd agree with you about not editing wordpress core files if I wasn't a coder. I've been doing this for quite some time. It's not an issue. But, thanks for the filter advice.

Comment: It *is* an issue, especially since this is for a client (unless you're disabling WordPress updates completely). Otherwise, changes to core files may be overwritten during a core update. There are times where editing the core is necessary...but this shouldn't be one of them.