# Log out of Wordpress password protected pages when browser closes

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, session-cookies

I want cookies for password protected pages in Wordpress to expire when the browser window closes. I've tried the following in my functions.php file with no luck:

```
function custom_password_cookie_expiry( $expires ) {
    return 0;  // Make it a session cookie
}
add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'custom_password_cookie_expiry' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging out of Wordpress password protected pages with cookie timout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639013/logging-out-of-wordpress-password-protected-pages-with-cookie-timout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem had been solved here. Please see the link:

```
function wpse_191369_post_password_expires() {
    return time() + 10; // Expire in 10 seconds
}

add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'wpse_191369_post_password_expires' );
```

**For more details:**

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191369/how-to-make-page-post-password-protected-so-you-must-reenter-everytime-you-visit

Comment: Why 10 seconds and not 0 seconds?

Comment: Sometimes, it doesn't work for "return 0;" then we set small time and it works. that's why I set 10 seconds.

Comment: Okay, Did you see the link?

Comment: Okay, Let me check it again at my machine.

Comment: Not really a good solution to set it to 10 seconds without knowing why it works.  Find the root cause as to why it's not working for 0 seconds.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz, Thanks, I will do

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is from frontend using javascript. Up on `onunload` event remove all or a specific cookie depending on your use case. Note that `onunload` event also fires when user navigates to other links or clicks on back button.

Comment: Can it be set in php.ini instead? Something like setcookie = 0?

Comment: You can't change cookie expiry time form php.ini. put this javascript on your page: jQuery( window ).unload(function() {for (var it in jQuery.cookie()) jQuery.removeCookie(it);}); this should remove all cookies which don't have any explicit path or not flagged as http only.